# Unable to call scripts from another namespace?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces

I am using the Oculus Interaction SDK within the Oculus Unity Package. I am having a circular namespace situation wherein I am not able to call my own scripts within Oculus.Interaction because my scripts themselves are part of their own namespace.

Without completely reorganizing my project hierarchy, how can I call functions from one namespace from another namespace, i.e. Oculus Interaction?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a namespace issue, but an assembly issue.

If you open VS2022 and open the Solution Explorer you will see that they're different assemblies and your Oculus assembly does not reference 'Assembly-C#-First-Pass'.

To fix that you'll need to do one of the following:

- Reference its asmdef
- Pull it outside any [Special Folders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html) it's in, (including Plugins folder)
- Delete the asmdef so it's part of your main assembly

[You can find more info about assembly definitions here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html).